# Spring MVC generate crud rest services Similar to JBoss Forge for Jax-rs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jboss-forge

I recently tried out JBoss Forge and immediately fell in love with the ability to mockup sample rest endpoints off of an existing relational database.  I have also been leveraging spring boot with a huge amount of satisfaction, but I was hoping to try and bring these two things together.  Is there anyway to generate a CRUD spring mvc restful webservice using JBoss Forge or something like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Spring Data Rest will actually be able to generate restful services on top of Spring Data JPA!  This is epic!

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/